# Golfing multiple curl statements in series

Tags: curl

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

URL_1=http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/

URL_2=$(curl "$URL_1" | sed -n '/Stable Versions/{p; :loop n; p; /rolling/Iq; b loop}' | grep -i rolling | cut -d \" -f 2)

URL_3=$(curl "$URL_1""$URL_2" | sed -n '/Latest/{p; :loop n; p; /.gz/q; b loop}' | grep .gz | cut -d \" -f 2)

wget "$URL_1""$URL_2""$URL_3"
```

Can I in any way shorten the above code to a single line of code ?

It is not good to define so many variables just to download something.

Comment: I added a one liner but I think it would be good if you clarify what your motivation is. If you want to write a readable script I wouldn't worry about multiple variables. If you're more in the golfing frame of mind that's different. Either way let us know.

Comment: You have 'golfing' in the subject, of course, but this doesn't look like a typical golfing problem...thus my request. Is it really for golf or just a personal desire to reduce the size? :)

Comment: @BLayer Isn't desire to reduce size of code code called golfing ? Yes, I want to reduce the size of code.

Comment: Golfing usually means a contest where you don't care how ugly the result is you just want the minimum number of characters. Is this for a contest?

Comment: @BLayer you deleted your answer ? Could you please share what you were working on?

Comment: Yeah, I decided I don't want to promote bad practices just for the sake of saving some characters. (There's a Stack Exchange code golf site if you want to pursue.) Did you not get a chance to copy what I had?

Comment: @BLayer I posted there but they closed the question suggesting it was off-topic and I ask somewhere else, so I deleted from there and asked here. I copied your answer but it seemed from your comments that you're done with the script and would be posting the `wget` one liner soon. Could you please share it. It is a different thing to promote one thing and different thing to help who are pursuing that thing itself, right ?!?

Comment: Actually your question might not be appropriate for this site either. It seems like an unorthodox request that would be of no use to anyone but yourself.... I haven't combined with wget yet. If you're not in a contest then what you have is better than my compressed version. It's perfectly okay to use multiple variables. Seriously. If someone comes up with a way to reduce the number of curl calls that could be something. But what I was doing was silly. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63399/discussion-between-gypsycosmonaut-and-b-layer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One liner, how was ordered :)**

`URL_1` variable is used for readability. It is not necessary.

```
#!/bin/bash

URL_1=http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/

curl "$URL_1" | 
grep -Pzo '(?s)Stable Versions.*?langpack' | 
sed -rn '$,$s_.*"(.*)">.*<td>(.*)</td></tr>.*_\1squid-\2.tar.gz_p' | 
xargs -I{} wget "${URL_1}"{}
```

1. `grep -Pzo '(?s)Stable Versions.*?langpack'`

   - `-P` Interpret  the  pattern  as  a  Perl-compatible  regular  expression.
   - `-z` option needed for multiline searching.
   - `-o` print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching  line.
   - `(?s)` It is turn on "dot matches newline" for the remainder of the regular expression. Information: [Inline Modifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers).
   - `.*?` non greedy matching.
2. `sed -rn '$,$s_.*"(.*)">.*<td>(.*)</td></tr>.*_\1squid-\2.tar.gz_p'`

   - build this part here: `v3/3.5/squid-3.5.26.tar.gz`
   - `$,$` process last line only.
   - I use the underscore instead of slash for the `s`ubstitute command, because of slashes in the `</tr>` and `</td>` tags. Example: `s_foo_bar_` instead `s/foo/bar/`
3. `xargs -I{} wget "${URL_1}"{}`

   - pass two concatenated parts to the `wget` by the `xargs`: `http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/` and
     `v3/3.5/squid-3.5.26.tar.gz`.

#### EDIT - version without xargs (it is unneeded here):

```
#!/bin/bash

URL_1=http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/

wget "${URL_1}$(curl "$URL_1" |
grep -Pzo '(?s)Stable Versions.*?langpack' |
sed -rn '$,$s_.*"(.*)">.*<td>(.*)</td></tr>.*_\1squid-\2.tar.gz_p')"
```

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut I squeeze code a little bit - `xargs` unneeded here.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your time and efforts.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner, using `lynx` rather han `curl`.

```sh
$ lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers \
  "$(lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers  http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/ | 
     awk '/^http:.*\/Versions\/v/ {print ; exit}')" |
  awk '/^http:.*\.tar.gz/ {print; exit}'
http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/squid-3.5.26.tar.gz
```

To make it actually download the latest stable version of the squid source, wrap the whole lot in `wget "$(....)"`

Comment: personally, i'd write something like this in perl, using LWP and probably HTML::Tokeparser or similar.  In fact, i've done so on several occasions.   `lynx`, though, is great for doing stuff like this from sh - it does all the html parsing for you and gives you nice, clean text to work with.